# Groovy: println vs System.out.println with GroovyInterceptable

Tags: groovy

Why do I need to use `System.out.println` instead of `println` when I use `GroovyInterceptable`?

For example if I am coding in a Groovy file I can just print to the console by typing:

```
println "Printing to Console"
```

But if I want to print here:

```
class Test implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def sum(Integer x, Integer y) { x + y }

    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        System.out.println "Invoke method $name with args: $args"
    }
}

def test = new Test()
test?.sum(2,3)
```

I have to use `System.out.println` in that method, or else I get a `StackOverflowError`. Why?

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Dan Getz for the answer below I know why it happens with the `GroovyInterceptable` class now. Does anyone know if there are other class implementations in Groovy where this issue could arise?

Comment: I edited your question a little to clarify that the "some cases" where you are needing to use `System.out.println` are when you are using `GroovyInterceptable`. Feel free to roll it back if I made it worse, and make whatever edits you think are best.

Comment: No that's ok, less is more in a question! So is it only when I use `GroovyInterceptable` that I need to use `System.out.println` or do I need to use it always within a class?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, sorry. Hopefully someone can give you a more general answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question at first. No you don't always need to use it inside a class, it's because of the `GroovyInterceptable`. I meant that I don't know if there are other situations in Groovy where using just `println` could be a problem.

Answer (score 9):

This is because your class `Test` implements the [`GroovyInterceptable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyInterceptable.html) interface, which according to the docs, is

> used to notify that all methods should be intercepted through the `invokeMethod` mechanism of `GroovyObject`.

This isn't just methods that have been defined on your class. Try:

```
test?.total(2,3)
```

You'll see that it returns

> Invoke method total with args: [2, 3]

The call to `println` inside `invokeMethod` is thus understood as a call to `this.println`, just like a call to `sum` would be. But `this.println` just calls `invokeMethod` again, because you implemented `GroovyInterceptable`, and so on.

This wouldn't happen if you didn't implement `GroovyInterceptable`. For example, running the following code

```
class Test {
    def sum(Integer x, Integer y) { 
        println "Let's sum!"
        x + y
    }
}

def test = new Test()
test?.sum(2,3)
```

Will output

> Let's sum!